# Multi platform 2D game engine

Tags: c#, android, ios, cross-platform, game-engine

I am creating a 2D game which I wish to run cross platform (on platforms such as Windows, Mac, iOS and Android as the main targets) and the engine I use needs to be open source. 
The main goal is to have the most code portability (possibly through scripting).

I would **prefer** to do this in C# but using another language is not a massive issue if I have to.

I have considered MonoGame and flash using the Flex SDK as they both claim to be cross platform and open source.

Which one of these would be a better choice considering my criteria? Or would another game engine/library be more suitable?

Comment: If you want to use Mono/MonoGame for iOS and Android, you have to get Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android, which both are not open source.

Comment: Is there a workaround using Objective-C/Java to load it?
Or is a different engine a better choice?

Comment: 'Torque' by Garage Games might work for your needs... you can code in their scripting language, which is very C-like, and publish to almost all relevant platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engines below allow you to reuse pretty much all your code, only thing you need to change is resolution and touch input/controls from desktop to mobile or the other way around. I would suggest you check out these engines, they are all open source:

- [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) - Uses Java and is almost as [fast](http://www.sparkrift.com/2012/1/love2d-vs-allegro-vs-clanlib-vs-libgdx-vs-cocos2d-x-vs-monogame-vs-xna-vs-sfml) as XNA, but faster than MonoGame. "Publish your games on Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS and HTML5, all with the same code base." - off their website, anything that can run java, can run your game. Big community so you shouldn't have problems asking questions when you need help and getting it.
- [Qt-Project](http://qt-project.org/) - Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language. As of Qt 5.1 you are supposed to be able to build for Android and iOS, allowing you to build for all the platforms you requested. Big community.
- [Moai](http://getmoai.com/) - Uses Lua and can deploy to all the platforms you requested. Only downside is the community is pretty small and the docs are a little out of date, but people on irc and forums will usually help you, but the answer won't always be immediate. You also have to build your own hosts to build for the platforms you desire, but last time I checked there were public hosts for all platforms out.

libgdx seems like a perfect fit for you. the performance is amazing, the community is big and it lets you reuse the same code for all platforms, just to name a few. Only downside being it doesn't use C#. Of course you should definitely look into them yourselves and see if they are match for what you want. I wish you the best of luck in your endeavors.

Comment: I have never seen any of these engines before, thanks for this! They appear to suit my needs well.

Comment: Is there a way to get libgdx working for iOS without using MonoDevelop and MonoTouch?

Comment: -1 for cocos2d, take a look at cocos2d-x it is cross platform so you dont have to change language, it uses C++ for all, and libgdx uses xamarin for ios which is not the native env. as it will trade off performance and some other things and also it requires license, $79 for students $299 for indies
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/features.html
@liam, xamarin, take a look at link above

Comment: I believe you can use Eclipse as well for Mac, check out http://hrugames.com/installing-libgdx-in-eclipse-tutorial/. I will also take edit my post, Onur is right, Cocos2D with C++ can build for the platforms you want now. When I looked into it a while ago it did not have that option, sorry for the confusion. You will not have to worry about the performance on iOS with libgdx, trust me. I personally use Moai because I am a fan of Lua, but the smaller community and crappy docs make it harder to catch onto.

Comment: I still believe libgdx is one of the best options since Java is quite heavily documented, make sure you check out more recent tutorials when you search though. Also don't be afraid to ask for help on the forums or even gamedev.net, as there are always tons of people willing to help you. You can use gamedev no matter what engine you use. I hope you find the engine that best suites your desires.

Comment: Also as a final remark, I strongly believe that your best choice is the one that feels most natural to you. It's definitely worth testing out the different engines a couple of days because you will be spending months afterwards creating your game in it. They are all great solutions. Look up sample codes for games using the engines and find something you like and prefer coding in, it will also help you stick with it more.

Comment: he can use libgdx for mac using Java but not for iOS. Building for iOS requires Xamarin which is .NET based, and it will trade off performance since building with .NET to iOS is not native.

Comment: I think I will go for libgdx as I know Java and not C++. Also, I believe there is a Java to Objective-C converter

Comment: And I've heard of codename one which can run Java on iOS

Comment: Codename One looks very interesting, nice find. You will not be having performance issues on iOS cuz .NET is not native, trust me. Unless you plan on creating some kind of tower defense where the person can have 50 towers on the map and then there are another 100 monsters on the map all getting shot at at once, then you don't really have nothing to worry about. I've never had any performance issues and I've used much slower options.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/). It is a 3D platform. But if you only use 2 dimensions you're good to go. In Unity3D you can write your game in C#, Javascript or Boo.

Unity is free and can export to Windows Phone, Windows 8 App, Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, Blackberry, iOs, Xbox360, Wii and PS3 but for those last 3 you need a developer license from Microsoft/Sony/Nintendo. But the possibility is there.

### UPDATE

You had to pay for the ios and android addons earlier. Now they are free:

> Today, we’re taking another step on this long road: as of right now,
>   independent Unity developers will be able to deploy their games to
>   Android and iOS platforms completely free of charge. Update Unity and
>   you will find Android and iOS build options (previously basic add-ons)
>   ready and waiting for you to use.

Source: [http://blogs.unity3d.com/](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/05/21/putting-the-power-of-unity-in-the-hands-of-every-mobile-developer/)

In the meanwhile, support for other platforms has come out (including windows phone, winrt & blackberry). Those are all free. If you want pro features you need a pro license. But most of the stuff you need is in the free version. To compare look at [this page](https://store.unity3d.com/).

Comment: Unity isn't open source.

Comment: Why does it need to be opensource if I may ask?

Comment: There are 2 main reasons.
1) Legalities. I am basically an amateur and can't pay a couple of hundred dollars to support these platforms.
2) If I want to modify a part of the engine (or add my own designer) I need access to the source.

Comment: Legalities? you do not need to pay to support those platforms, they work out of the box, exept for Xbox360, Playstation & Wii but for those you need a developer license. The rest works out of the box. And if you wish, you can make your own physics engine.

Comment: To my knowledge you had to pay for the iOS and android exporters. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, like you said, had to pay... not anymore they made it free.

Comment: I was completely unaware of this. This makes unity now a good choice for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options based on your preferences; I will list a couple of ones I recently come across.

1. Cocos2d series seem very popular these days. If you think C++ isn't
   a problem for you then Cocos2d-X would be an option as it offers a
   lot of platforms. Other Cocos2d series might get your attention as
   well. I guess there are a couple of versions like HTML5, Javascript,
   Python. etc but i think only cocos2d-x is cross platform.
2. Unity3D(C#, Javascript, Boo) seems as an option but it's not open
   source, as well as UDK(UnrealScript) also same, but if you think to
   buy a license they offer source code I guess
3. Flash also can be a good option, as you mentioned. It uses AS3 which
   is an OOP language and can be very useful if you are a beginner.
4. And ImpactJS offers a lot of platforms also, it uses HTML5, you can
   check here http://impactjs.com/

The list can be longer and longer, and depends on your needs. You should specify your needs clearly like; how much deep you wanna go, which platforms are most important for you? etc.

Good Luck

Comment: Cocos2D is seeming to be very appealing now. And I would like to support as many platforms as possible.

Comment: yeah it's very popular these days, and i think when you begin one of them it is easier to switch to the other one e.g cocos2d-iphone -> cocos2d-x

Comment: I'll see how this goes

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: http://www.appgamekit.com/ (AGK)
Code in c++, but working perfectly. A very simple engine.